# MediaLibrarySession Causing ANR

Tags: android-media3

I am developing a media playing app, in which I am using `MediaLibraryService` to play music in background. I am using `Media3` libraries. I have created a playback service class and created instances of `MediaController` in `MainActivity` class. But during run time I get error

> ANR in com.example...
> Reason: executing service com.example....PlaybackService

Can anyone kindly solve the problem. i.e. how to call service class in another thread or coroutine. I am developing in Kotlin.